# How to split and add individual values in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, for-loop

In my javascript, I've an array named `my_array` holding values like `0121`, `1201`, `0012`, `0202` etc.

Each individual digit in the string is of importance. So, in the above example, there are 4 values in one string. E.g. `0121` holds 0,1,2,1.

The values can also be longer too. E.g. `01221`, `21021` etc. (This is holding 5 values)

I want to know of the easiest and most effective way to do the following:

Add the first digits of all the strings in the array `my_array`. E.g. `0+1+0+0` in the above example

Add the second digits (e.g. `1+2+0+2`) and so on.

I can loop through the array and split the values, then

```
for(i=0; i<my_array.length; i++){
    var another_array = my_array[i].split();
    //Getting too complicated?
}
```

How can I do it effectively? Someone please guide me.

Comment: what is the type of my_array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
var myArray = ["0121", "1201", "0012", "0202"];
var firstValSum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var firstVal = myArray[i].split("");
    firstValSum += parseInt(firstVal[0], 10);
}

console.log(firstValSum); //1
```

This could be wrapped into a function which takes parameters to make it dynamic. i.e pass in the array and which part of the string you want to add together.

**EDIT** - This is a neater way of achieving what you want - this code outputs the computed values in an array as you specified.

```
var myArray = ["0121", "1201", "0012", "0202"];
var newArr = [];    

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var vals = myArray[i].split("");
    for(var x = 0; x < vals.length; x++) {
        var thisVal = parseInt(vals[x], 10);
        ( newArr[x] !== undefined ) ? newArr[x] = newArr[x] += thisVal : newArr.push(thisVal);
    }
}

console.log(newArr); //[1, 5, 3, 6];
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JrBp2/1/)

Comment: Looks great. I want to add all the parts. In this example, I would say an array with 4 results holding all the four sums.

Comment: @LittleLebowski - see the edit i've made. The second block of code does exactly that :)

Comment: Awesome, looks great. Let me test this on my code. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: No worries, i've not explained the code much, so let me know if you need any explanation of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood it myself. :D

Comment: And it works like a charm. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
var resultArray = new Array();    // This array will  contain the sum.
var lengthEachString = my_array[0].length;    

for(j=0; j<lengthEachString ; j++){     // if each element contains 4 elements then loop for 4 times.
    for(i=0; i<my_array.length; i++){    // loop through each element and add the respective position digit.
        var resultArray[j] = parseInt( my_array[i].charAt(j) );   // charAt function is used to get the nth position digit.
    }
}
```

Comment: `int lengthEachStrng` <- this isn't valid JavaScript. This should simple be `var lengthEachStrng = my_array[1].length;`.